# How can i make the body of my snake expand?

Tags: c++, sfml

Ive been trying to recreate snake as my  first project in sfml, and after getting most of the work done ive ran into the issue of making the snake body expand. This was my first idea

```
for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
        {
            RectangleShape tail(Vector2f(20.0f, 20.0f));
            tail.setFillColor(Color::Green);
            tail.setPosition((float)bodyX[i], (float)bodyY[i]);
            window.draw(tail);
        }
```

So i wanted to ask if there is some line of code that im missing that would help me out, or if i need to change it entirely in order to make it work

Some code that i use the arrays for and the code that i declared the bodyX and bodyY arrays with is

```
Vector2f snekPos = snek.getPosition();

int bodyX[40] = {snekPos.x}, bodyY[30] = {snekPos.y}; 
        for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
        {
            bodyX[i] = bodyX[i-1];
            bodyY[i] = bodyY[i-1];
        }
```

Comment: That entirely depends on `bodyX` and `bodyY`; how do you manage these? Show the code that updates these array during normal navigation and then also what happens when the tail is supposed to grow.

Comment: In general, the length of the snake increases by moving the head and not moving the tail (or erasing the last tail segment).

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use a better datastructure for managing your tail segments:

```
std::list<sf::Vector2f> tail;
```

In a normal update you simply prepend the new head position and remove the last segment:

```
tail.push_front(snekPos);
tail.pop_back();
```

If the snake eats an apple (or candy, or small furry animal), you can increase the length by simply duplicating the tail segment before the update:

```
tail.push_back(tail.back());
```

Your drawing loop is now simpler, too:

```
RectangleShape segment(Vector2f(20.0f, 20.0f));
segment.setFillColor(Color::Green);
for (const auto & segmentPos: tail) {
    segment.setPosition(segmentPos);
    window.draw(segment);
}
```

Comment: well i did what you said but as soon as the new part of the body comes on screen it dissappears

Comment: also the body still cant expand more than once

Comment: Can't help you without seeing more code, but you made sure that `tail` is not recreated every frame, right?